# Have fixed speed with AddForce?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, move, physics, rigid-bodies

I want to use AddForce to move an object with a fixed speed but when I use AddForce the speed of the rigid body increases in crescendo.
AddForce adds a force to me every time I hold the input down, the more I hold the key to move the object the more force is added, while I always want to move the object with the same force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set the velocity directly instead of adding accelerated force every frame you hold down the button. So instead of using AddForce(), you can access your rigidbody's velocity [like in this example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html).

Comment: But this involves problems with the physic.
On the other hand, I just want to apply an always equal force to move the rigidbody in linear speed, but only for that occasion. (for example a car walking at low speed or a man walking..their have a constant speed that does not grow with continuing input)

Comment: I don't understand why velocity does not work for you. You want the rigidbody to move with a constant speed every frame, right? Then use this code in `FixedUpdate()`:
`object.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector(1,0,0); `

If you want to assign the velocity only once, just apply it once when you are holding the button down and set the velocity to 0 when you stop pressing the button.

Comment: I just wanted to say, that, will speed be affected if it receives a push in the opposite direction from where it moves? or so as long as I hold the input buttondown the speed of the rigidbody will always be that even if it receives other external forces?

Comment: Velocity means constant speed, so yes. It should move with constant speed as long as you hold down your input button. External forces such as collisions might change your rigidbody's course, but you can avoid that by checkig isKinematic to true. You can read more on that here: http://resetoter.cn/UnityDoc/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html

Comment: No, I want him to react to external forces at that speed so is ok, thanks

Comment: @DanielePappalardo same problem with me, you found any solution?